# CentOSにPostfixがインストールされているか確認したい

Tags: centos, postfix

**Q1.CentOS 7 には Postfix がデフォルトでインストールされていますか？**

---

**Q2.今現在、下記状態なのですがどういう意味ですか？**
・yumではインストールされていないけれども、Postfix は存在している？
・/etcに postfixがあるからと言ってインストールされているとは限らない？？

```
# yum list installed | grep postfix
```

・何も表示されない

```
# ls /etc
```

> postfix

---

**環境**
・CentOS 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CentOSは配布形態がいくつかあるので(通常版, netinstall, minimal, etc...)、どの手段を使ってインストールしたかにもよると思います。

完全なパッケージ名が分かっているなら`rpm -q <PACKAGE>`や`yum list <PACKAGE>`で確認する方法もあります。

```
$ rpm -q postfix
postfix-2.10.1-6.el7.x86_64

$ yum list postfix
インストール済みパッケージ
postfix.x86_64     2:2.10.1-6.el7     @anaconda

# 未インストールの場合は以下の様な表示
利用可能なパッケージ
postfix.x86_64     2:2.10.1-6.el7     @anaconda
```

`etc/postfix`が存在するのは [tanalab2](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/28902/tanalab2) さんも言及している通り、過去にパッケージがインストールされていたが手動、または自動でパッケージが削除され、設定ファイルのみ残っている可能性があります。
この辺りの挙動は過去質問でも[回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/41994/3060)しています。

Comment: rpm -q postfixで、パッケージ postfix はインストールされていません。と表示されました。現在「未インストール」であることが分かったので、これから新規インストールすることにします

Answer (score 1):

> Q1.CentOS 7 には Postfix がデフォルトでインストールされていますか？

以下によると、`最小限のインストール`のパッケージに`postfix`は入っているようですので、デフォルトでインストールされると思います。

[CentOS 7インストーラの「ソフトウェアの選択」の中身を調べてみた](https://qiita.com/yunano/items/5a3687c5cd2007b3e720)

> Q2.今現在、下記状態なのですがどういう意味ですか？

`postfix`のパッケージがインストールされていないということだと思います。(他のMTAパッケージをインストールした等の理由により削除された。)

パッケージは削除されたが、`postfix`の設定ファイル格納用ディレクトリ(`/etc/postfix/`)が残ってしまった状態ということだと思います。

Comment: 「他のMTAパッケージをインストールした等の理由により削除された」そういう理由で削除されることもあるのですね。何れにしても現在「未インストール」であることが分かったので、これから新規インストールすることにします

Answer (score 1):

```
# rpm -qf /etc/postfix
ファイル /etc/postfix はどのパッケージにも属していません。
```

このように表示されれば、インストールされていません。

`yum history package-info postfix` を実行すると過去にインストールされていたかなど、わかるかもしれません。

Comment: yum history package-info postfix実行したら、インストール後削除していました。ただ、インストールの開始時間が2016と表示されていた意味が分かりませんでした(CentOS7自体をインストールしたのが2018なのに……)

Comment: 2016と表示されたのはいわゆるプリインストールなんだと思います。